# Simple module not working - property * does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, tsconfig, bootstrap-confirmation

I am tried write custom module to this [confirmation-plugin](http://bootstrap-confirmation.js.org/) . And during compiling ts, throw exception Property confirmation does not exist on type 'JQuery' . This is my code blocks:

-ts.config

```
{
"include": ["./app/Resources/public/ts/*" ],
"compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "dom.iterable"],
    "typeRoots" : ["node_modules/@types", "./app/Resources/public/ts/types"]
}
```

}

module

```
declare module 'bs-confirmation' {
interface JQuery {
    confirmation: any;
}
```

}

my-script

```
    private againInitConfirmation() {
    $('[data-toggle=confirmation]').confirmation({
        rootSelector: '[data-toggle=confirmation]',
    }); // error Property confirmation does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'
}
```

dir-structure

```
-ts-config
-app
  -Resources
   -public
    -ts
     *ts-files
     -types
       bs-confirmation.ts
-node_modules
 -etc.
```

When i copy and past bs-confirmation.ts to node_modules/@types/etc. and add `///<reference types="jquery"/>`
this is working. What am i doing wrong ? What to do to make it work in a custom directory ? Sorry my bad english . Best regards. Andrew